# AS3 event handler in child object is not firing

Tags: actionscript-3

Maybe I missed some point along the way when learning AS3 and event handling. Anyways, the loader's complete event (onLoad) is not firing for the loader within the imgManager object. If I copy the same code in the main class and ask it to fire the same event from within itself it works fine. Here is my code:

```
public class ImageScroller extends Sprite
{
    public function ImageScroller()
    {
        var imgMan:ImageManager = new ImageManager();
        var v:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        v[0] = "../assets/apache_pb.gif";

        imgMan.LoadImages(v);

        addChild(imgMan.loadedImages[0]);
    }

}

public class ImageManager
{
    public var _loader:Loader;
    private var _urlRequest:URLRequest;
    private var _loadedImages:Vector.<Bitmap>;

    public var bo:Boolean = false;

    public function ImageManager()
    {
        _loader = new Loader();

        _loadedImages = new Vector.<Bitmap>();
    }

    public function LoadImages(v:Vector.<String>):void
    {

        for(var i:int = 0; i < v.length;i++)
        {
            _loader.load(new URLRequest(v[i]));
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
        }

    }

    private function onLoad(e:Event):void
    {
        bo = true;
        var bmp:Bitmap = (Bitmap)(e.target.content);
        _loadedImages[0] = bmp;
    }

    public function get loadedImages():Vector.<Bitmap>
    {
        return _loadedImages;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code and believe the following is the solution to you problem:

Main.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            var imageScroller:ImageScroller = new ImageScroller("images/image1.jpg",
                                                                "images/image2.jpg",
                                                                "images/image3.jpg");
            addChild(imageScroller);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

ImageScroller.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ImageScroller extends Sprite
    {
        private var _urls:Array;
        private var _imageManager:ImageManager;

        public function ImageScroller(...urls:Array)
        {
            _urls = urls;

            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            _imageManager = new ImageManager();
            _imageManager.load(_urls);
            _imageManager.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageManagerComplete);

        }// end function

        private function onImageManagerComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            addChild(_imageManager.bitmaps[0]);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

ImageManager.as

```
package
{   
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class ImageManager extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var _urls:Array;
        private var _bitmaps:Vector.<Bitmap>;
        private var _loadedBitmapCount:int;

        public function get bitmaps():Vector.<Bitmap>     
        {       
            return _bitmaps;  

        } // end function

        public function ImageManager()     
        {
            init();

        }// end function 

        public function load(urls:Array):void   
        {
            for each(var url:* in urls)
            {
                if(!(url is String))
                throw new ArgumentError("Arguments must be of type String");

            }// end for

            _urls = urls;

            for(var i:int = 0; i < _urls.length; i++)  
            {    
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.load(new URLRequest(_urls[i]));     
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);    

            }  // end for 

        } // end function

        private function init():void
        {
            _bitmaps = new Vector.<Bitmap>();

        }// end function

        private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
        {   
            if(++_loadedBitmapCount >= _urls.length)
            {
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

            }// end if

            var bitmap:Bitmap = (Bitmap)(e.target.content); 
            bitmaps.push(bitmap);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

The problem you where having was that you tried to access the loaded images before they were loaded.

```
imgMan.LoadImages(v);   
addChild(imgMan.loadedImages[0]);
```

What you needed was an event listener that would listen for your `ImageManager` object to dispatch an event when it had loaded all the images. To do this, I first changed your `ImageManager` class from an `Object` to an `EventDispatcher`.

```
public class ImageManager extends EventDispatcher
```

Now the `ImageManager` has the two methods needed to dispatch an event and listen for it which are respectively the `dispatchEvent()` and `addEventListener()` methods.

Next I changed the code so that condition would test to see if all the images where loaded on each call to the `onLoaderComplete` event handler when the `loader` objects when the event listeners call it. This was done with the help of the `_loadedBitmapCount` integar property that incremented on each call then tested its value against the length of the `_urls` array property's length property. When the condition was met, the `ImageManager` `EventDispatcher` object would call its `dispatchEvent()` method and dispatch an `Event.COMPLETE` event object.

```
public function load(urls:Array):void   
{
    // ...

    for(var i:int = 0; i < _urls.length; i++)  
    {    
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(_urls[i]));     
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);    

    }  // end for 

} // end function

//...

private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
{   
    if(++_loadedBitmapCount >= _urls.length)
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));

    }// end if

}// end function
```

Finally I changed the code in the `ImageScroller` class by adding an event listener that listened for the `ImageManager` object to dispatch the `Event.COMPLETE` event object. When this would happen and the `onImageManagerComplete()` event handler was called, now the  loaded images were accessible, because now they had been infact loaded.

```
private function init():void
{
    _imageManager = new ImageManager();
    _imageManager.load(_urls);
    _imageManager.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageManagerComplete);

}// end function

private function onImageManagerComplete(e:Event):void
{
    addChild(_imageManager.bitmaps[0]);

}// end function
```

If there is anything you didn't understand or want to ask me about, just add a comment to this answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks. What I don't get is why I need to add an event listener for the main class.

Comment: Hey, thanks. A couple things.

1. Why did I need to put an event listener on the main class?

2. Do events span multiple classes? In the above, ImageManager has a loader object which spawns the Complete event. Is the Complete event (caused by the loader object), seen at all by ImageScroller or is it just contained within the ImageManager class?

3. Based on the answer above, does the dispatchEvent above only run through the context of the ImageScroller class and not Main for example?

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer the questions you've asked the best that I can, but some I couldn't because I don't know how to answer them properly. I suggest googling the "event flow in flash" which is really the subject of your question. I did explain it partially though in another question which you can find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364839/as3-problem-with-event-handling/4364896#4364896.